# C++ - make tupple from variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have C++11 code with variadic template class

```
template <typename R, typename ...ARGS>
class MyFunction
{
}
```

I have a methods defined like this

```
template <typename T, typename T2>
void Callback()
{
    MyFunction<T, T2> * fptr12 = (MyFunction<T, T2> *)f;
    fptr12->args = std::make_tuple(GetInput<T2>());
    fptr12->call();
}

template <typename T, typename T2, typename T3>
void Callback()
{
    MyFunction<T, T2, T3> * fptr12 = (MyFunction<T, T2, T3> *)f;
    fptr12->args = std::make_tuple(GetInput<T2>(), GetInput<T3>());
    fptr12->call();
}
```

`f` => defined as interface `IFunction` in a dictionary (it is retrieved from dictionary based on other parametrs, but correct function is always returned, so it can be casted)

I want to make method `Callback` universal for any number of arguments (Tx), so it can work with any `MyFunction`. I can add variadic template to it, but I dont know, how to generate tupple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to expand the variadic argument list:

```
template <typename T, typename... Tn>
void Callback() {
    MyFunction<T, Tn...>* fptr = static_cast<MyFunction<T, Tn...>*)(&f);
    fptr->args = std::make_tuple(GetInput<Tn>()...);
    fptr->call();
}
```

Comment: It is woking, but GetInput<Tn>() is called in reversed order (Tn, Tn-1), which is problem, if all parameters are not same...

Comment: @MartinPerry: note that the order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified. That is, the same is true for your code spelling out the argument explicitly. If you want to order the evaluation of arguments I think you can use aggregate initialization: `std::tuple<Tn...>{ GetInput<Tn>()... };` (however, I'd need to trawl through the standard to see if aggregate initialization guarantees the order of initializers and to see whether `std::tuple<...>` actually does support aggregate initialization.

Comment: I have tried it and it seems to work on my example. But I am not sure if it is just "chance" or it will work always. From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) I understand that this is C++17 feature - _"Conditionally-explicit constructors in C++17 make it possible to construct a tuple in copy-initialization context using list-initialization syntax: "_

Comment: @DietmarKühl `tuple` isn't an aggregate, but the sequencing guarantee applies to all braced-init-lists, not just aggregate initialization, so you are safe.

Comment: @MartinPerry `std::tuple<Tn...>{ GetInput<Tn>()... }` is a direct-initialization context, not a copy-initialization context.

Comment: @T.C.: good point - I need to be more careful about the details of the initialization. I'm aware that `std::tuple<T...>` isn't an aggregate thought that curlies still work - I simply forgot about direct-initialization. Thanks for clarifying!